# migration oracle app to postgresql date/time field value out of range: "1400-02-29 00:00:00 AD"

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-fdw

Im migrating an application from oracle to postgresql. In one of the functions that I already migrated I copy data from a different oracle db (db link in oracle, oracle_fdw extension in postgresql) from a few tables into a local table in my postgresql db. However, I`m getting the next error :

```
 NOTICE:  Insert data into table from remote table : insert into IP_MAN 
 select * from IP_MAN_production
 NOTICE:     PROCEDURE copy_table : V_Step = 4 // **SQLERRM = date/time field 
 value out of range: "1400-02-29 00:00:00 AD"**
 CONTEXT:  converting column "birthday" for foreign table scan of "ip_man_production", 
 row 32481
```

When I try to select the specific row in the oracle db I get the next value :

```
select date from bezeq.ip_manuim where 
birthday=to_date('29/02/1400','dd/mm/yyyy');

  birthday
  --------
 01010001
```

birthday is datatype is timestamp without time zone.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are the birthdays by chance only recorded using month and date, not taking the year? If that's the case, an `UPDATE` query setting their years to 2000 could fix your issue, if the month and date are all that matter.

Comment: most of the values in this column are in format dd/mm/yyyyy but as you can see I mentioned the output that i got when i selected the table.

Comment: You've given us the `date` field output, but `birthdate` is the problematic one.

Comment: no no , i wrote date but i was mistaken - it was birthday

Comment: Hi, I updated the value and it fixed my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL thinks that 1400 was no leap year.

See this definition in [`src/include/utils/datetime.h`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/utils/datetime.h):

```c
/*
 * These are the rules for the Gregorian calendar, which was adopted in 1582.
 * However, we use this calculation for all prior years as well because the
 * SQL standard specifies use of the Gregorian calendar.  This prevents the
 * date 1500-02-29 from being stored, even though it is valid in the Julian
 * calendar.
 */
#define isleap(y) (((y) % 4) == 0 && (((y) % 100) != 0 || ((y) % 400) == 0))
```

As the comment says, it is technically wrong to reject `1400-02-29`, but it is justified with a vague mention of the SQL standard. I don't know if the argument is valid, but I won't dig deeper since it seems that you have solved your peoblem.

Comment: Indeed, I solved my problem. So technicly, I cant insert any date before 1582 into postgresql tables ?

Comment: You absolutely can insert dates down to 4713 BC, but PostgreSQL will treat leap years according to the Gregorian calendar, although in the Julian calendar that was in effect before 1582 every fourth year was a leap year (which caused the seasons to shift forward). But all this, although exciting to anybody with a bend for masochism, is probably not important to your use case.